# PySide QGraphicsView size

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsview

I have 2 issues with QGraphicsView.

I can't get the size of the QGraphicsView object. All methods I'm using is giving me values I wouldn't expect.

If I print out the mouse's position on the area's lower-right corner (scrollbars included), I get a random 400 value. After setting sceneRect to 500 I was expecting to get that back.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene( QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self) )
        self.setSceneRect( 0, 0, 500, 500 )

        print self.viewport().width() # outputs 96
        print self.width() # outputs 100
        print self.rect() # outputs QRect(0, 0, 100, 30)
        print self.size() # outputs QSize(100, 30)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print event.pos().toTuple() # prints (413, 423) at lower-right corner

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.view = View(self)
        hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.view)

        buttonsLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(10):
            newButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
            buttonsLayout.addWidget(newButton)
        hLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

        self.tempButton = QtGui.QPushButton()

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tempButton)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def run(self):
        self.show()

win = MainWindow()
win.run()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, I believe you are not getting the sizes you are expecting for two reasons:

1. You are not explicitly setting the size of the `QGraphicsView` widget to 500, but the `QGraphicsScene` instead.
2. You are fetching the sizes too early in the construction of your application, before the layout of the `MainWindow` has been properly painted.

Regarding your second issue, depending of what is desired, it is possible to use the method [mapFromScene](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsView.mapFromScene) to get the position of the mouse event in regard to the `QGraphicsScene` instead of the `QGraphicsView` widget.

More specifically, this can be achieve in your code by:

1. Setting the size of the `QGraphicsView` widget with `setFixedSize` ;
2. Moving the "size-fetching" calls in the `run` method, after the `MainWindow` has been painted ;
3. Adding a `mapToScene` transformation on the `mouseMoveEvent` coordinate.

Below is the code that was modified accordingly to the points listed above:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class View(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self) )
        self.setSceneRect( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 )
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print
        print self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toTuple() 
        # prints (1000, 1000) at lower-right corner
        print event.pos().toTuple()
        # prints (500, 500) at lower-right corner

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.view = View(self)

        hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.view)

        buttonsLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(10):
            newButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
            buttonsLayout.addWidget(newButton)
        hLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

        self.tempButton = QtGui.QPushButton()

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tempButton)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def run(self):
        self.show()  
        print
        print self.view.viewport().width() # outputs 485
        print self.view.width() # outputs 500
        print self.view.rect() # outputs QRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        print self.view.size() # outputs QSize(500, 500)
        print self.view.sceneRect() #outputs QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MainWindow()  
    win.run()  

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With the code above, the value returned for the size of `QGraphicView` is 500x500, while it is 1000x1000 for the `QGraphicsScene`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation!